# Using Events with the Application Object in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, add-in

Ms Word does not want to load my add-in. I want to call a userform on print event. Here is my code:

in module 1

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforePrint(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)
'Debug.Print Now & " " & "App_DocumentBeforePrint: " & Wb.FullName
Userform1.Show
End Sub

Sub InitializeApp()
Dim X As New EventClassModule
Set X.App = Word.Application
End Sub
```

in Document module

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
Call InitializeApp
End Sub
```

in EventClassModule

```
Public WithEvents App As Word.Application
```

in Userform1 Mode

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize()
End Sub
```

I used this 2 links to help me write this code

1) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221264%28v=office.12%29.aspx

2) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597509%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Can anyone tell why my code does not work?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the first link you show, the procedure **App_DocumentBeforePrint** needs to be in the CLASS module (EventClassModule, in your explanation), not in Module 1.

Other than that, it's not clear what you mean by "my add-in". Usually, I'd think of a template (or COM add-in) when this term is used that's being loaded as an add-in. I'm concerned whether Document_Open is actually being triggered to initialize your events. This event, in the ThisDocument module (in reality, it's a class) will only fire when the document containing this code is opened...

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else who comes across this thread like I did, this is what worked for me:

in module 1
(your module shouldn't contain the event-based sub; also, X needs to be declared as a global variable rather than within the 'InitializeApp' sub)

```
Option Explicit

Dim X As New EventClassModule

Sub InitializeApp()
    Set X.App = Word.Application
End Sub
```

in Document module

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    Call InitializeApp
End Sub
```

in EventClassModule
(your Class Module should contain the event-based sub)

```
Public WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforePrint(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)
    '''Your procedure here
End Sub
```