# Is it possible to trigger some event when a comment is added or deleted in MS Word using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, comments

In MS Word, when adding a comment to a text selection, I would like to change the background color of this selection if the comment contains some "keyword".
Then obviously, if the comment is deleted or doesn't contain the "keyword", I need to remove this color/highlight to the scope text.

I managed to do it on the global 'run macro' with this code (except the remove part), but ideally this should be dynamic and activates when the focus changes back from the comment to the document or anything else.

Here is a simplified version of my code attempt so far:

```
'
' ColorComments Macro
'

Dim wdCmt As Comment, cat As String, pg As Paragraph
  
  For Each pg In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
      
    'Trying to reset the background colors before reapplying the active ones but doesn't work
    pg.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = 0
  
  Next

  For Each wdCmt In ActiveDocument.Comments

    With wdCmt
          
      If Trim(.Range) = "keyword" Then
                       
        'Probably a better way to change the background color of the text that would give me access to more colors?
        .Scope.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = 2
          
      Else
      
        'resetting the comment "Scope" color if it doesn't contain the code
        .Scope.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = 0

      End If

    End With

  Next

End Sub
```

I guess I should use the pulic events or the `WindowsSelectionChange` event but I can't find a documentation about it anywhere.
I've little to no experience in VBA so thanks in advance for awy help :)

Comment: Please, try looking [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/objects-properties-methods/using-events-with-the-application-object-word) and see how to create and use Word Application events.

Comment: Try this: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067563/using-events-with-the-application-object-in-ms-word)

Comment: Thanks @FaneDuru I saw that but it doesn't give a clue about the events that are available or triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make that work effectively you will need to repurpose these two controls from the RibbonUI:

```
ReviewNewComment
ReviewDeleteComment
```

Here are a couple of links to articles on repurposing RibbonUI controls
https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/repurpose_user_interface_controls.html
https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/21499/Intercepting-Office-Ribbon-Control-Events-with-VBA-using-Repurposing-Commands.html

In prior versions of Word, I don’t recall seeing what version you are trying to use, VBA solutions could access the following event routine:

```
Sub InsertNewComment()
'
' InsertNewComment Macro
' Insert comment (includes menu)
'
End Sub
```

And even though this routine still works if you invoke it directly from VBA, this is not what is used from the RibbonUI in today’s versions of Word. I know that because I’ve tried to trap the event using the subroutine but haven’t been successful.

The following VBA routine is invoked by clicking on the Insert Ink Comment on the RibbonUI.

```
Sub InsertInkComment()
'
' InsertInkComment Macro
' Insert ink comment
'
    Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range

End Sub
```

It’s a mystery why this one works and the other does not and that is why I said upfront that you will have to trap and repurpose the RibbonUI, particularly for regular comments.

As for trapping the Delete Comment event, there isn’t a DeleteComment VBA routine that I have found. There are event routines for Deleting All Comments but none for a single comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It would be for MS Office for Mac, 16.40. 
I'll have a look at your suggestion later today and come back to you.